# "Second derivative" of Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am looking at a paper considering Thomae's function. Its continouity and differentiation remain clear to me. The authors suggest that it is pointless to look for the classical second derivative, but they consider $$f_*=\lim_{h\to\infty} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))-(f(x)-f(x-h)}{h^2}$$ instead. It is not said why is it a proper choice for something equvialent to second derivative. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Is it just differential quotient of differential quotiens?

Comment: Differentiation should be independent of the direction you are taking the limit to. Write down the difference quotient and replace $h$ by $-h$ and this is how you get it. In the RHS of your equations, write it as a left and right difference quotient to see that it is a difference quoient using the first derivative.

Comment: Might be helpful here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient#Second_order